# How do I enable SAP GUI scripting on my Cloud Appliance Library Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sap-gui, netweaver

I am a DevOps noob so please bear with me, and I would really appreciate it if you could provide step by step instructions.

I am trying to enable SAP GUI Scripting on my Cloud Appliance Library SAP instance that is running NetWeaver 7.5 hosted on AWS. Though it's hosted on AWS I can suspend / activate the instance by logging into my account at cal.sap.com

Here are the exact instructions I'm trying to follow: https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/how-to-enable-sap-gui-scripting

The steps listed in the article are

1. Login to your SAP server
2. Specify the parameter name sapgui/user_scripting and click Display. If "Parameter name is unknown" appears in the status bar, this indicates that you are missing the current support package. Check your installed packages. Change the value of sapgui/user_scripting to TRUE.
3. Click Save.

I can't even figure out how to do Step 1. How do I "Login" to my SAP server? I can see buttons to suspend and activate the instance in the CAL web portal / dashboard, but I'm not sure how to "login". Do I need to do this through AWS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For logging into server, you should connect it:) And for this you need something more than your instance in CAL. You need client called [SAPgui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAPgui)

Brief installation manual can be found here:

http://www.hec.ca/dti/assistance/pedagogie/logiciels_enseignes/sap_gui_install.html#Installation